# error due to f2py not installed correctly: how do I correct?

Tags: python

http://software-lisc.fbk.eu/bdg/
I am trying to run the BdG-TMAT code. The folder here has both Fortran and python files since the main run file BDG_K.py uses some fortran functions. So to run the fortran code, I use a converter f2py which converts tmatf.f90 to tmatf.so. f2py comes auto-installed with numpy. From make of BdG-Tmat, I get the following error due to a problem with f2py:

```
- f2py -lgsl -llapack -lcblas -c potsub.f90 potsubi.o -m potsub 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/f2py", line 3, in <module>
    import f2py2e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/f2py2e/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import f2py2e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/f2py2e/f2py2e.py", line 26, in <module>
    import crackfortran
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/f2py2e/crackfortran.py", line 1588
    as = b['args']
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
make: *** [potsub.so] Error 1
```

I am unsure how to correct this, though I have checked out crackfortran.py
Please help.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Could you post the output of make in the BdG-TMAT directory?

Comment: @metacom : Thanks, it seems there was a problem with make which I was ignoring. I shall write back to you if it does not work.

Comment: @metacom : Please check the update in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug is caused by `as` becoming a keyword in Python 2.6 (see also http://bugs.python.org/issue8031). The current version of numpy no longer contains this bug:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/f2py/crackfortran.py

The (assumed) offending line has moved to line 2126 and now reads `args = block['args']`.

So the solution will be to get a recent version of numpy or an pre-2.6 version of Python.